# How to filter $ value on php

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to filter value

example:
`112` to be `01:12`

from script

```
$duration = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'TMDB_Runtime', true ); 
if ( ! empty( $duration ) ) {
echo '<div class="gmr-duration-item" property="duration">' . $duration . __( ' <a class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></a>','movies' ) . '</div>';
```

I've tried using substr and str_replace and put it into function.php

```
<?php
$text = '$duration';
$text = substr($text, 0, 3);
echo $text =str_replace("1","01:", $text);
?>
```

But always display parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way, statically:

```
<?php
$duration = "112";
$exploded = str_split($duration);
$exploded[0] = "0".$exploded[0].":";

$final = implode($exploded);
echo $final;
?>
```

Comment: thanks dude :). That is true method, its working, but... the `$duration` its not always `112` value, I mean, get value from $duration (eee) and filter it to (ee:ee)

Comment: But it will always have 1,2,3 or 4 numbers to be a time. So you could first check string length, then have a switch statement for if it's 1, 2, 3 or 4, apply a 0:# or #:#, etc

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I am noticing in this code snippet:

```
<?php
$text = '$duration';
$text = substr($text, 0, 3);
echo $text =str_replace("1","01:", $text);
?>
```

First:
`echo $text =str_replace("1","01:", $text);` is incorrect syntax. You can't assign a function to a function. Split it into two lines.

```
$text = str_replace("1","01:", $text);
echo $text;
```

Second:
`$text = '$duration';` is not setting `$text` to `112`. It is setting it to the literal string `$duration`. Single-quotes in PHP do not evaluate variables, that is what double-quotes do. So, try this instead:

```
$text = "$duration";
```

Comment: Yes I know it, On the `$duration` should be `112` and `echo $text =str_replace("1","01:", $text);` should be `01:01:2`  this is just an example, because I already do not know how